# Coverting data back to Rust which is pass to Lua using mlua

Tags: rust, lua

I'm using [mlua](https://crates.io/crates/mlua/) crate

Im passing a struct to Lua as UserData which is mutable and Lua can modify the data,

```rust
let lua = Lua::new();
let mut cars = Cars::new();
cars.add_car("Toyota".to_string(), "Corolla".to_string());
lua.globals().set("Cars", cars)?;
```

and I should be able to pull the data back to Rust as its original Struct

```rust
let final_cars: Cars = lua.globals().get("Cars")?;
```

But the problem is I'm not sure how to convert the UserData back to Rust Struct when implementing the [FromLua](https://docs.rs/mlua/0.9.5/mlua/trait.FromLua.html) trait

Here's the Full code

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use mlua::{ FromLua, Lua, LuaSerdeExt, Value, Result, UserData, UserDataMethods};

#[derive(Default, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone )]
struct Car {
    brand: String,
    model: String,
}

impl UserData for Car { }

#[derive(Default, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone )]
struct Cars {
    list: Vec<Car>
}

impl Cars {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { list: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_car(&mut self, brand: String, model: String) {
        self.list.push( Car { brand, model } );
    }
}

impl UserData for Cars {
    fn add_methods<'lua, M: UserDataMethods<'lua, Self>>(methods: &mut M) {
        methods.add_method_mut("add", |_, this, (brand, model): (String, String)| {
            println!("added car lua [brand: {}, name: {}]", &brand, &model);
            this.list.push( Car { brand, model });
            println!("{:#?}", this.list);
            Ok(())
        });
    }
}

impl<'lua>FromLua<'lua> for Cars {
    fn from_lua(value: Value<'lua>, lua: &'lua Lua) -> Result<Self> {

        // I cannot transform the userdata back to Cars
        // I've got an error saying "Error: DeserializeError("invalid type: userdata, expected table")"
        let list: Cars = lua.from_value(value)?;
        Ok( list )

    }

}

fn main() -> Result<()> {

    let lua = Lua::new();
    let mut cars = Cars::new();
    cars.add_car("Toyota".to_string(), "Corolla".to_string());

    println!("{:#?}", &cars);

    lua.globals().set("Cars", cars)?; //lua.create_ser_userdata(routes)? //lua.to_value(&routes)?

    lua.load(r#"
        local cars = Cars
        cars:add("Toyota", "Lua")
        cars:add("Honda", "Lua")

        print( type(cars) ) -- userdata 
        print( typeof(cars) ) -- Cars
    "#).exec()?;

    let final_cars: Cars = lua.globals().get("Cars")?;

    println!("Final car\n{:#?}", final_cars);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `from_value` and the error message tell you that you can only use from_value to convert tables to structs (and probably primitives to primitives). Since your type is a userdata, you can use `value.as_userdata` and `AnyUserData::borrow` to convert back to a reference to `Cars`

Comment: thanks, seems to work with `let list: Cars = value.as_userdata().unwrap().take().unwrap();`